# How can i add component(products) to another component(cart)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ProductCard

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Container, Row, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Cart from './Cart';
import './ItemCard.css';

function ProductCard(props){



    return(
     <Card className="card-style" border="primary" style={{widht:'18rem', flex: 1}}>
     <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.product.image} />
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{props.product.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>Price: ${props.product.price}, Quantity: {props.product.quantity}
            </Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">Add to Cart</Button>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    
    )
}

export default ProductCard
```

Cart

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, thead, tr, th} from 'react-bootstrap';

function Cart (){
    return(
        <div>
            <Table striped border hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product.</th>
                        <th>Price.</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Cart;
```

I have my components cart and productcart. In this case im trying to add my products in cart component when press the button "add to cart", i´m new in react and laravel so i dont have idea how can i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to create state in Product component and pass the state to Cart component when clicked on add to cart button.

Product Cart

```
import Cart from './Cart';

 function ProductCard (props) {
 
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
 
   function handleAddItems () {
 
      setItems([
        ...items,
        {
          name: props.product.name,
          price: props.product.price,
          quantity: props.product.quantity
        }
      ]);
 
    }
 
     return(
      ..
         <Button variant="primary" onClick = {handleAddItems}>Add to Cart</Button>
      ..
      <Cart items={items}></Cart>
     )
 }
```

Cart

```
function Cart ({items}) {

 .. 
  console.log(items);
 ..

}
```

Comment: but the problem is in <Cart items = {items}> </Cart> because if I want to create a table in the cart component, it shows me the table in the component product.

Comment: In that case, you need to create a component which wraps both `Cart` and `Product` component and set the state in wrapper component and finally pass the state value to `Cart` component.